# Create the configuration file at maven install and without or before feature install for Karaf

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

In my project, in the bundle module, at `resource` directory, I have my sample `startup.cfg` file. This file contains properties I want to use at the startup. In the bundle `pom.xml` I have the following.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-artifacts</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <artifacts>
              <artifact>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/classes/startup.cfg</file>
                <type>cfg</type>
                <classifier>config</classifier>
              </artifact>
            </artifacts>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And in my feature xml, I have,

```
<feature name="my-sample-feature" description="Sample service" version='${project.version}'>
    <bundle>mvn:org.sample.app/service.implementation/{{VERSION}}</bundle>
    <configfile finalname="/etc/org.sample.app.startup.cfg">mvn:mvn:org.sample.app/service.implementation/{{VERSION}}/cfg/config</configfile>
</feature>
```

In feature xml, I have added,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>service.implementation</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <classifier>config</classifier>
  <type>cfg</type>
</dependency>
```

This feature is a startup feature too. Now, when I install the feature in a karaf container or in this case when I spin up the karaf, only then the `etc/org.sample.app.startup.cfg` is created. My target is simple, to have this conf file always at `etc/` independent of the feature is installed or not.

Comment: I don't understand. When you start karaf the feature is installed, but the config file is not created? Your posted feature seems to be malformed, could you paste the exact content of the feature.xml that is deployed to your maven repository?

Comment: Perhaps the maven assembly plugin could help (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html)

Answer (score 0):

The cfg file are deployed into etc folder when installing the feature . If you want it to be present independent of the feature is installed or not, this means that you have to deploy it manually to etc and this is more simple after attaching the cfg to your artifact as you did in your pom.

Remember that if you want to follow best pratices (especially in a production environnement), don't separate cfg deployment from it's origin feature.